# TEST Mirror default database but no data

Tags: django

I am trying to set up some testing on my Django application. I have used a database mirror for the test database. When I try to run few test it appears the data from 'default database' is not available in the mirror test database.

```
'default': { #'sqlite': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'OPTIONS':{
            'timeout': 180,
        },
        #  'TEST':{
        #     'MIRROR': 'default',
        #
        # }


    },
'replica': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'OPTIONS':{
            'timeout': 180,
        },
        'TEST_MIRROR': 'default'


    }
```

my tests:

```
data_school = DataSchool.objects.all()
self.assertTrue(data_school.exists())
```

I am confused, the test_mirrors configured by the database administrator as a read replica of default database.and in theory any data in default database should be available for test? If I have any configuration errors  please do let know. Thanks

Comment: +1 having the same problem - records created in 'default' DB aren't found in 'replica' DB despite settings 'TEST_MIRROR' or 'TEST':{'MIRROR': 'default'} being set for the 'replica' db settings

Comment: FWIW this appears to be a bug in Django: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23718

Answer (score 10):

This is a known bug in Django:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23718

The workaround described in that ticket is your best bet. I ran into this same issue and implemented the workaround by defining a custom TestCase class and inheriting from that custom test case in all my tests. I also chose to use setUpClass and tearDownClass instead of setUp and tearDown as described in the bug ticket. Either should work though.

```
from django.db import connections

class CustomTestCase(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(CustomTestCase, cls).setUpClass()
        connections['replica']._orig_cursor = connections['replica'].cursor
        connections['replica'].cursor = connections['default'].cursor

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        connections['replica'].cursor = connections['replica']._orig_cursor
        super(CustomTestCase, cls).tearDownClass()
```

Comment: I think this solution stops working with django 2.2

Comment: It worked with Django 3.0.x and pytest, by using [module level setup/teardown](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/xunit_setup.html#module-level-setup-teardown)

Answer (score 0):

**Simple approach if you want to use only "default" database in tests**

1. Define settings as

```
DB_MAIN_KEY = 'default'
DB_REPLICA_KEY = 'replica'

DATABASES = {
    DB_MAIN_KEY: {...},
    DB_REPLICA_KEY: {...,
        'TEST': {'MIRROR': DB_MAIN_KEY},
    },
}
```

2. Use **override_settings** on your test class (base test class)

```
from django.test import override_settings, TestCase
from django.conf import settings

@override_settings(DB_REPLICA_KEY=settings.DB_MAIN_KEY)
class YourTest(TestCase):
   pass
```

3. Additional reading

- [Database settings - Mirror](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#mirror)
- [Testing with multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/testing/advanced/#topics-testing-primaryreplica)